# Azure DevOps pipelines VS Test failures. All those unit tests are passing locally

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have a .Net framework 4.7.1 solution with two projects. In that one is for unit tests. Those unit tests are running successfully in local but not running in Azure Pipelines.

**Pipeline:**

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2WYE.png)

YAML Below,

> #Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘BuildPlatform’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
> #Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘BuildConfiguration’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
>
> steps:
>
> - task: VSTest@2   displayName: 'Test Assemblies'   inputs:
>   testAssemblyVer2: |
>   **\bin\debug\VentureAccess5NunitTest.dll
>   !***TestAdapter.dll
>   !**\obj**
>   vsTestVersion: toolsInstaller
>   platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
>   configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'

**Below is the error log:**

[Job Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxKb4.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BCRn.png)

> ```
>     2021-04-21T22:17:33.7444190Z **************** Starting test execution *********************
> 2021-04-21T22:17:33.7577516Z [command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\VsTest\16.9.4\x64\tools\net451\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe
> ```
>
> "@D:\a_temp\vgsj2dnktuj.tmp"
> 2021-04-21T22:17:33.9074880Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.9.4
> 2021-04-21T22:17:33.9075586Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> 2021-04-21T22:17:33.9229321Z vstest.console.exe "D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\bin\Debug\VentureAccess5NunitTest.dll"
> 2021-04-21T22:17:33.9230164Z /Settings:"D:\a_temp\j4c4nybwlvx.tmp.runsettings"
> 2021-04-21T22:17:33.9230650Z /Logger:"trx"
> 2021-04-21T22:17:33.9231040Z /TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\8\s"
> 2021-04-21T22:17:35.1891001Z Starting test execution, please wait...
> 2021-04-21T22:17:35.8177732Z A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
> 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0142297Z   Failed DocDelvAuditTest [15 s]
> 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0269893Z   Error Message:
> 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0271211Z    Unable to create instance of class VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest. Error:
> System.Exception: Application Key: SQLCommandTimeOut not found.    at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0272513Z    at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String Key). 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0273141Z   Stack Trace: 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0273699Z       at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String Key) 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0274405Z    at VentureAccess5.DAL.Database..ctor() 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0274954Z    at VentureAccess5.Models.DocDelvEmail..ctor() 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0277235Z    at VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest..ctor() in D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\Model\DocDelvEmailModelTest.cs:line 29 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0278511Z   Standard Output Messages: 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0279077Z  log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge]. 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0279660Z  log4net: Logger [root] Level string is [ALL]. 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0280320Z  log4net: Logger [root] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648]. 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0281128Z  log4net: Loading Appender [RollingLogFileAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0282039Z  log4net: Setting Property [File] to String value [D:\\DebugLogs\\VentureAccess50Dev.log] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0282811Z  log4net: Setting Property [AppendToFile] to Boolean value [True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0283501Z  log4net: Setting Property [RollingStyle] to RollingMode value [Size] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0284203Z  log4net: Setting Property [MaxSizeRollBackups] to Int32 value [10] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0284846Z  log4net: Setting Property [MaximumFileSize] to String value [1MB] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0286546Z  log4net: Setting Property [StaticLogFileName] to Boolean value [True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0287306Z  log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0288078Z  log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0288908Z  log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0289714Z  log4net: Converter [p] Option [] Format [min=5,max=2147483647,leftAlign=True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0291911Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0297285Z  log4net: Converter [d] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0298738Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0300034Z  log4net: Converter [r] Option [] Format [min=5,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0300823Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ms ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0301568Z  log4net: Converter [c] Option [1] Format [min=22,max=22,leftAlign=True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0302349Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0303092Z  log4net: Converter [M] Option [] Format [min=18,max=18,leftAlign=True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0303851Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ - ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0310200Z  log4net: Converter [m] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0312287Z  log4net: Converter [n] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0313144Z  log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0313920Z  log4net: Searched for existing files in [D:\DebugLogs] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0314646Z  log4net: curSizeRollBackups starts at [0] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0315899Z  log4net: Opening file for writing [D:\DebugLogs\VentureAccess50Dev.log] append [True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0316649Z  log4net: Created Appender [RollingLogFileAppender] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0317349Z  log4net: Adding appender named [RollingLogFileAppender] to logger [root]. 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0317966Z  log4net: Hierarchy Threshold [] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0318406Z   2021-04-21T22:17:54.0318814Z Debug Trace: 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0319315Z log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge]. 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0319893Z  log4net: Logger [root] Level string is [ALL]. 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0320554Z  log4net: Logger [root] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648]. 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0321380Z  log4net: Loading Appender [RollingLogFileAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0322290Z  log4net: Setting Property [File] to String value [D:\\DebugLogs\\VentureAccess50Dev.log] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0323066Z  log4net: Setting Property [AppendToFile] to Boolean value [True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0323956Z  log4net: Setting Property [RollingStyle] to RollingMode value [Size] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0324668Z  log4net: Setting Property [MaxSizeRollBackups] to Int32 value [10] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0325784Z  log4net: Setting Property [MaximumFileSize] to String value [1MB] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0326487Z  log4net: Setting Property [StaticLogFileName] to Boolean value [True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0327224Z  log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0327944Z  log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0328761Z  log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0329556Z  log4net: Converter [p] Option [] Format [min=5,max=2147483647,leftAlign=True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0330315Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0331097Z  log4net: Converter [d] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0331871Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0332656Z  log4net: Converter [r] Option [] Format [min=5,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0333361Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ms ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0333990Z  log4net: Converter [c] Option [1] Format [min=22,max=22,leftAlign=True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0334724Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0336066Z  log4net: Converter [M] Option [] Format [min=18,max=18,leftAlign=True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0336746Z  log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ - ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0337497Z  log4net: Converter [m] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0338245Z  log4net: Converter [n] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0339015Z  log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0339633Z  log4net: Searched for existing files in [D:\DebugLogs] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0340225Z  log4net: curSizeRollBackups starts at [0] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0340980Z  log4net: Opening file for writing [D:\DebugLogs\VentureAccess50Dev.log] append [True] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0341662Z  log4net: Created Appender [RollingLogFileAppender] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0342326Z  log4net: Adding appender named [RollingLogFileAppender] to logger [root]. 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0343202Z  log4net: Hierarchy Threshold [] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.0492287Z log4net: Shutdown called on Hierarchy [log4net-default-repository] 2021-04-21T22:17:54.1082194Z NUnit Adapter 3.17.0.0: Test execution started 2021-04-21T22:17:54.3154715Z Running all tests in D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\bin\Debug\VentureAccess5NunitTest.dll 2021-04-21T22:17:54.9317980Z    NUnit3TestExecutor discovered 239 of 239 NUnit test cases 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4623137Z   Failed DocDelvAuditTest_Negative [3 ms] 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4624317Z   Error Message: 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4625714Z    Unable to create instance of class VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest. Error: System.Exception: Application Key: SQLCommandTimeOut not found.    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4627189Z    at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String
> Key).
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4628800Z   Stack Trace:
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4639153Z       at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String
> Key)
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4640388Z    at VentureAccess5.DAL.Database..ctor()
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4641271Z    at VentureAccess5.Models.DocDelvEmail..ctor()
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4644686Z    at VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest..ctor() in
> D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\Model\DocDelvEmailModelTest.cs:line
> 29
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4653553Z   Failed GetEmailImageUrlTest [1 ms]
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4654749Z   Error Message:
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4657218Z    Unable to create instance of class VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest. Error:
> System.Exception: Application Key: SQLCommandTimeOut not found.    at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4658473Z    at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String Key). 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4665795Z   Stack Trace: 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4666361Z       at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String Key) 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4666992Z    at VentureAccess5.DAL.Database..ctor() 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4667461Z    at VentureAccess5.Models.DocDelvEmail..ctor() 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4668265Z    at VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest..ctor() in D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\Model\DocDelvEmailModelTest.cs:line 29 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4669143Z   Failed GetNextUniqueIdTest [1 ms] 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4669563Z   Error Message: 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4674006Z    Unable to create instance of class VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest. Error: System.Exception: Application Key: SQLCommandTimeOut not found.    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4683289Z    at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String
> Key).
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4684012Z   Stack Trace:
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4684678Z       at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String
> Key)
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4685367Z    at VentureAccess5.DAL.Database..ctor()
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4685943Z    at VentureAccess5.Models.DocDelvEmail..ctor()
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4686869Z    at VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest..ctor() in
> D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\Model\DocDelvEmailModelTest.cs:line
> 29
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4687746Z   Failed GetRetEmail [1 ms]
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4688235Z   Error Message:
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4689308Z    Unable to create instance of class VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest. Error:
> System.Exception: Application Key: SQLCommandTimeOut not found.    at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4690713Z    at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String Key). 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4691348Z   Stack Trace: 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4691976Z       at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String Key) 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4692959Z    at VentureAccess5.DAL.Database..ctor() 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4693514Z    at VentureAccess5.Models.DocDelvEmail..ctor() 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4694411Z    at VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest..ctor() in D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\Model\DocDelvEmailModelTest.cs:line 29 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4695281Z   Failed GetRetEmail2 [1 ms] 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4695762Z   Error Message: 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4696850Z    Unable to create instance of class VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest. Error: System.Exception: Application Key: SQLCommandTimeOut not found.    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4698326Z    at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String
> Key).
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4698938Z   Stack Trace:
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4699578Z       at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String
> Key)
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4700226Z    at VentureAccess5.DAL.Database..ctor()
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4700806Z    at VentureAccess5.Models.DocDelvEmail..ctor()
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4701713Z    at VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest..ctor() in
> D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\Model\DocDelvEmailModelTest.cs:line
> 29
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4702577Z   Failed GetSkipEmailData [1 ms]
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4703074Z   Error Message:
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4704340Z    Unable to create instance of class VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest. Error:
> System.Exception: Application Key: SQLCommandTimeOut not found.    at
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4705809Z    at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String Key). 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4706424Z   Stack Trace: 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4707047Z       at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String Key) 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4707729Z    at VentureAccess5.DAL.Database..ctor() 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4708295Z    at VentureAccess5.Models.DocDelvEmail..ctor() 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4709203Z    at VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvEmailModelTest..ctor() in D:\a\8\s\VentureAccess5NunitTest\Model\DocDelvEmailModelTest.cs:line 29 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4710089Z   Failed DocDelvAuditTest [3 ms] 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4710716Z   Error Message: 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4711786Z    Unable to create instance of class VentureAccess5NunitTest.Model.DocDelvFaxTest. Error: System.Exception: Application Key: SQLCommandTimeOut not found.    at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
> 2021-04-21T22:17:55.4712961Z    at VentureAccess5.ApplicationSettingConfig.GetApplicationConfigurationValueByKey(String
> Key).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use self-hosted agent if you don't mind, then your apps are equivalent to running locally and won't be subject to Azure DevOps billing restrictions.

Click [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#microsoft-hosted-agents) for detailed information about self-hosted agent and Microsoft-hosted agent.

Click [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for tutorials on creating self-hosted agents:

If you want to use Microsoft-hosted agent, here are some troubleshooting advices:

1. The Classic UI pipeline uses `vs2017-win2016` agent by default, which does not support many new features. I suggest you use the `windows-2019` agent.

   [image]
2. Make sure all paths in your apps are relative paths. Microsoft-hosted agents don't read your local content, so if you need local references, you should upload them to the repository, or download them to the agent via NuGet restore, cmd etc.
3. Similar to 2, [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md) is a list of downloaded software of the Microsoft-hosted agent. Please check if there are any software you need, but the Microsoft agent does not have downloaded. You need to download them before your run test task.